# Are there two different versions of the \mathcal{F} character?

Tags: fonts, computer-modern, tex-history, mathcal

I've seen two different versions of the `\mathcal{F}` character:

Version 1 (see the `\mathcal{F}`):

[image: version 1]

Version 2:

[image: version 2]

Notice that the top horizontal line of the F curves down on the left much more in version 1 than it does in version 2.

Which of these is the preferred `\mathcal{F}`? I know that some of the calligraphic capital letters were improved at one point, but I don't know which version is the improved one.

UPDATE OF 8/2/2017: Just today I did the automatic update of my MiKTeX---I am currently using pdfLaTeX, pdfTeX Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (MiKTeX 2.9.6400), and TeXworks Version 0.6.2---and my `\mathcal{F}` has gone back to the old one. No other characters in any fonts seem to have changed. However, if I add the `lmodern` package, I can get the new `\mathcal{F}` in both regular and bold forms. Did something happen with the current version of MiKTeX?

Comment: Hi MSC, please note that you can include images using one of icons on top of the edit box. You have now enough reputation points to do this.

Comment: the link for the first version of the example has gone dead.  would it be possible to recreate the example, and add it via the recommended image upload?

Comment: Can you provide the correct image for version 1?

Comment: Okay, I found an image that should show the "old" `\mathcal{F}`. Sorry it's a little fuzzy.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The final version of Computer Modern's mathcal F is the second one. To see it, you can compile with metafont the file `cmsy10.mf` (located in `[texmf]/fonts/source/public/cm/`; be sure you have the [latest version](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/cm/mf/)). Here is the result, after conversion in dvi format with `gftodvi`:

[image: mathcal F compiled from the sources]

If you compare the type 1 versions of Computer Modern, you see that the Bluesky/AMS and Latin Modern versions both have the right version. However, old versions of Latin Modern have the wrong mathcal F:

[image: comparison of mathcal F between the bluesky and lmodern versions]

This means that if you use a recent TeX distribution, you should always have the final version ofthe mathcal F.

As an aside, my version of *Computer Modern Typefaces*, although recent, still shows the old version:

[image: mathcal F from the Computer Modern Typefaces book]

Comment: Thank you. Is there also a new-style bold `\mathcal{F}`? My system uses the new-style normal `\mathcal{F}` but the old-style bold `\mathcal{F}`. I've noticed this discrepancy in a few other PDFs I've found on the web, too.

Comment: @MSC: yes, the bold also has a new version, but it's not in the Bluesky/AMS fonts. You can find it in the latest version of Latin Modern. So if your TeX distribution is recent, using `\usepackage{lmodern}` will ensure you're using the latest versions.

Answer (score 12):

If you include the command `\usepackage{eucal}`, then `\mathcal{F}` will produce the curlier one and `\CMcal{F}` will produce the other.  It's up to you to decide which you prefer.

To more directly answer your question: Including the command `\usepackage{eucal}` changes the `\mathcal` command so that it will produce the curlier one; omitting that package will make `\mathcal` produce the less curly one.

Comment: It is not possible to use the `eucal` package to switch between the two versions show by MSC. Both of MSC's examples come from the Computer Modern font whereas `eucal` uses the Euler font, which is completely different (the most visible difference being that it is upright instead of slanted).

Comment: Oops!  I guess I should have looked more closely at those "F"s.