# Different \mathcal O

Tags: fonts, math-mode

I would like to get a script O looking like this:

[image]

However, `\mathcal O` and `\mathscr O` give [image], which are slightly different.

This is **not** the pre-1992 `\mathcal O`.

Comment: Old versions of Computer Modern mathcal was available in old versions of Latin Modern, but the O looks nothing like the one you are showing (the changes were minor, see [what happened to the F](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11265/are-there-two-different-versions-of-the-mathcalf-character)). Your O is more like a variant of mathscr so you could look at "English Script" fonts on a site like myfonts to see if you find something similar (for example, [English 111](http://myfonts.us/td-XRrNOL) is a bit closer). From which book(s) does it come from ?

Comment: Hartshorne's *Algebraic Geometry* uses it on page 69.  It also appears in an old (pre-TeX) [article](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0001870871900272) (I'll try to upload a scan tomorrow) which also has a *very* exotic script A.

Comment: OK, that's the script used on monotype machines which you can see in the books about monotype technology (e.g. Chaundy's *The Printing of Mathematics* or Monotype's *List of Mathematical Characters* for 4-line mathematics). I'm not sure it's available as a digital font, though. I'll upload a scan later on for you to see. Fonts called [Commercial Script](http://new.myfonts.com/search/commercial+script/fonts/) come close, but it's not quite that yet.

Comment: @YuriDelanghe This questions seems borderline for TeX.sx. As far as I can see, you want a particular font which we have no idea has ever been available as a TeX font. At the very least it would be useful to know the source of your graphic.

Comment: @JosephWright Yes, I hadn't realized that Hartshorne might be non-TeX.

Answer (score 3):

`\mathscr{O}` from the [`euler`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/euler) package is thinner than the one from [`mathrsfs`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathrsfs), which you obviously use:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{euler}
\begin{document}
$\mathscr{O}$
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Still different than the one above, though... I'm looking for that specific O.

Comment: Then scan it, and insert the picture. Unless you can provide us some insight as to which font this is, there is not much we can do.

Answer (score 3):

Run with `xelatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{STIX Math}
\begin{document}
\Huge $\mscrO$
\end{document}
```

[image]

`amsmath` is not needed here but it is always a good idea to load it and that must be done *before* `unicode-math`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem you had trying to get some equations out of Laeqed that uses TeX so I guess is the same.

In my case I discovered that the font by default was set to be Times New Roman, so I tried to change the font back to the standard one and when i compiled again the problem solved by itself and the `$\mathscr{O}$` changed back to `$\mathcal{O}$`.