# Font for sheaves in Hartshorne

Tags: fonts

What is the font used in Hartshorne's *Algebraic Geometry* book for sheaves? I originaly thought it was `\mathscr` as `$\mathscr F$` looks very much like the symbol for a sheaf F there. But that can not be, because `$\mathscr O$` looks just so different from the symbol for the structure sheaf in the cited book. There it looks closer to `$\mathcal O$`, though it is not quite that either.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: Looks like [Ralph Smith's Formal Script](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/rfsf/) to me.

Comment: Btw, as Corentin already said: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How do I find out what fonts are used in a document/picture?](http://goo.gl/YsWvA)

Comment: Perhaps I was not clear enough: I am not looking for a generic way to identify a font (which is what the suggested link provides); I am really asking how to reproduce in LaTeX the specific font used for sheaves in Hartshorne. I do thus not believe my question is answered in the refered link.

Comment: I found the following post http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37519/different-mathcal-o which is about trying to find O in that specific font, where the issue does not seem to be resolved.

Comment: @user46792: the issue is resolved, as the font has been identified in the comments of the question you refer to. As far as I know it has never been digitalized, so you won't find it exactly.