# How to use fonts (the ones listed in mathalfa documentation) in math mode

Tags: math-mode, fonts, amsmath

I was looking for more fonts like `mathcal`, `mathbb` to use them in math mode, so I can distinguish different quantities, and I found [this answer on TeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58098/what-are-all-the-font-styles-i-can-use-in-math-mode?answertab=votes#tab-top) to the question

> [What are all the font styles I can use in math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58098/what-are-all-the-font-styles-i-can-use-in-math-mode)

In the first answer there is a list of all usable fonts in math mode which can be found at the end of the [`mathalfa` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mathalfa/doc/mathalfa.pdf) and it's like

[image]

Now, I read the poor documentation on the `mathalfa` package, without understanding enough to get those fonts. My question is: how do I use those fonts in math mode? Which package do I need to use them? 
What are the commands with which I can choose between fonts?

Basically what I would like is something like (just to make an example)

```
Text [...] $\esstix{A} = \euler{A}$
```

What do I have to do? Even a more complete documentation with some examples would be good...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll post my own answer as I found a pretty simple way to achieve the resut I was looking for.
With the command `\DeclareMathAlphabet`, which syntax is

```
\DeclareMathAlphabet{<math-alph>}{<encoding>}{<family>}{<series>}{<shape>}
```

you can define `<math-alph>` to be a new math alphabet.

> The arguments `<encoding>`, `<family>`, `<series>`, `<shape>` are the default
>   values for this math alphabet in all math versions; these can be reset
>   later for a particular math version by a [`\SetMathAlphabet`](http://tex.loria.fr/ctan-doc/macros/latex/doc/html/fntguide/node16.html) command. If
>    is empty then the  is declared to be invalid in all
>   versions, unless it is set by a later `\SetMathAlphabet` command.
>
> Checks that `<math-alph>` can be used and that `<encoding>` is a valid
>   encoding scheme.
>
> In these examples, `\foo` is defined everywhere but `\baz`, by default, is
>    defined nowhere.
>
> ```
> \DeclareMathAlphabet{\foo}{OT1}{cmtt}{m}{n}
> \DeclareMathAlphabet{\baz}{OT1}{}{}{}
> ```
>
> (from [Index of /ctan-doc/macros/latex/doc/html/fntguide](http://tex.loria.fr/ctan-doc/macros/latex/doc/html/fntguide/node16.html))

All the combination available with the [`mathalfa`](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mathalfa) package are available in the source code of [`mathalfa.sty` on GitHub](https://github.com/rogerberm/thesis/blob/master/mathalfa.sty). Another list, with all the font abbreviation can be found on the [`mathalfa` documentation](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/mathalfa/doc/mathalfa.pdf) (at the end of the pdf).

I found particularly illuminating the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165621/how-to-insert-a-special-math-alphabet) provided by the user [`cfr`](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mathalfa), which I thank for the illustration of the use of command 
`\DeclareMathAlphabet`.

I'll provide a simple example for future visitors:

```
%PREAMBLE
\DeclareMathAlphabet\mathzapf{T1}{pzc}{mb}{it}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathchorus}{OT1}{cmtt}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet\mathrsfso{U}{rsfso}{m}{n}
% ...

%DOCUMENT
\[
    \mathzapf{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}
\]
\[
    \mathchorus{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}
\]
\[ 
    \mathrsfso{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}
\]
```

which output is

[image]

Answer (score 9):

mathalfa allows you to map fonts to the four standard command `\mathcal`, `\mathscr`, `\mathfrak`, `\mathbb`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[cal=esstix,frak=euler,scr=boondox,bb= pazo]{mathalfa}
\begin{document}
$\mathcal{Esstix ABC}=\mathfrak{Euler ABC}= \mathscr{Boondox ABC}=\mathbb{Pazo ABC}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to have more than one style with newcommand or something like that, in addiction to `\mathcal`, `\mathscr`, `\mathfrak`, `\mathbb`?

Comment: Yes, with \DeclareMathAlphabet or with \newcommand. You only need to find out the needed nfss-declarations. Look in the code of mathalfa.

Comment: Could you provide an example for defining a single letter in a certain font, even with a new command?