# Can you help add this font to my math font list?

Tags: math-mode, fonts

I found a PhD thesis using a math font I did not know yet:

[image]

I know these: `\mathbb{}`, `\mathcal{}`, `\mathfrak{}`, `\mathscr{}`, `\mathsf{}`, `\EuScript{}`, but none of these match the symbols above. Help me expand my library of symbols I can use!! :D

**EDIT:** Now I want to know how to make a new command in this font, without 'overwriting' the above commands. For example if I use `\mathcalpxtx{XUY}`, I will end up with the XUY in the image above. I tried to do this with [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/384937/how-to-use-fonts-the-ones-listed-in-mathalfa-documentation-in-math-mode) question, but I actually don't understand how this declare operator works...

Comment: A good set of font specimens, with instructions for how to use them, is [here](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mathalpha/doc/mathalpha-doc.pdf).

Comment: You will rarely if ever want to use two different calligraphic alphabets in an actual math paper. Mathematicians who do would usually make them very distinct styles, such as a chancery-style alphabet as `\mathcal` and a script-style alphabet (what `mathalpha` calls “embellished”) as `\mathscr`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be the calligraphic font often used with Times or Palatino clones. You can set `\mathcal` to this font with the option `cal=pxtx` from [`mathalpha`](https://ctan.org/pkg/mathalpha), as in the following example.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[cal=pxtx]{mathalpha}
\begin{document}
\(\mathcal{XUY}\)
\end{document}
```

If you want to keep using the default calligraphic font as well, you can define the new alphabet without loading `mathalpha` and associate it with another command than `\mathcal`. To define the new alphabet, you can take the relevant lines directly from `mathalpha`'s code.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{txcal}{\skewchar \font =45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{txcal}{m}{n}{<-> txr-cal}{}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathcalpxtx}{U}{txcal}{m}{n}
\begin{document}
\(\mathcal{XUY}\mathcalpxtx{XUY}\)
\end{document}
```

Comment: Or possibly `txupr` for the less-slanted version.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. Note to other readers of this question. The math alpha package provides quite a number of alternative fonts for the commands I mentioned in my question!

Comment: @Davislor maybe, but from the OP's picture I think it is really the italic version.

Comment: @seaver indeed! This package is very easy to use, and its documentation is very helpful.

Comment: Vincent and @Davislor Do you know how to solve my edited question?

Comment: @seaver I edited my answer to add another solution that should work.

Comment: Great! You're the man! This allows for defining all the fonts in the `mathalpha` manual! :D