# Using DeclareMathAlphabet and Mathalpha

Tags: math-mode, alphabet, mathalfa

This is a question related to:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/384959/88262

`DeclareMathAlphabet` requires 4 arguments, of which the first specifies the encoding and the second specifies the font. However, not all encodings are compatible with all fonts. Is there a list of which encoding to choose for which font? The links in the answer above are all dead and looking into either the mathalpha documentation or `mathalpha.sty` itself did not help.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathalfa}
\DeclareMathAlphabet\mathzapf{T1}{pzc}{mb}{it}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathchorus}{OT1}{cmtt}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet\mathrsfso{U}{rsfso}{m}{n}
% \DeclareMathAlphabet\mathesstix{???}{esstix}{m}{n} % which encoding to choose? 
                                                     % neither T1, OT1 or U work

\begin{document}
\[ \mathzapf{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ} \]
\[ \mathchorus{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ} \]
\[ \mathrsfso{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ} \]
% \[ \mathresstix{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ} \]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You Might Have an XY-Problem

If you’re defining Zapf Chancery and Ralph Smith Formal Script Oblique as math alphabets, you almost certainly want the former to be `\mathcal` and the latter as `\mathscr`.  (You might only have done your MWE that way as an example, however.)  If you find yourself actually using more script alphabets than that in the same paper, you should seriously reconsider your notation.

What you really want to do is load your `\mathscr` and `\mathcal` alphabets with [`mathalpha`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mathalpha/doc/mathalpha-doc.pdf), as in:

```
\usepackage[cal=zapfc, scr=rsfso]{mathalpha}
```

In this case, you would want

```
\usepackage[scr=esstix]{mathalpha}
```

which loads the following commands:

```
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{esstixscr}{\skewchar \font =45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{esstixscr}{m}{n}{
  <-> \mathalfa@scrscaled  esstixcal}{}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathscr}{U}{esstixscr}{m}{n}
```

The remaining command is named `\mathchorus`, implying that it’s intended to set up TeX Gyre Chorus, a clone of Zapf Chancery.  However, it actually selects Computer Modern Sans Serif.  This is not a useful thing to do; if you want to use Chorus, use it instead of the default PostScript `pzc` (which might be different fonts on different systems), and if you want Computer Modern Sans Serif as an alphabet that isn’t the main alphabet, use it as `\mathsf`.

### The Literal Answer

While the font encodings are normally in the package documentation, LaTeX’s New Font Selection Scheme (NFSS) searches for files named [encoding][family].fd.  (On OSes such as Linux where it matters, the encoding is lowercase in the filename but uppercase in your document commands.)

So, your examples correspond to the files `urfsfo.fd`, `t1pzc.fd` and `ot1cmss.fd`.

You can therefore search your TeX directory for files matching this naming scheme.  For example, on the Ubuntu command line, you could search for all encodings for either the `pzc` family (Zapf Chancery) or `qzc` (TeX Gyre Chorus, the clone that actually comes with TeX) with the command:

```
find /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/ -name "*[pq]zc.fd" -print
```

If you just want to check whether a specific family comes in a specific encoding, you can test whether a specific filename is in TeX’s database with `kpsewhich`. For example, to confirm that `cmr` comes in the `OML` encoding:

```
kpsewhich omlcmr.fd
```

Or, all modern file managers have a file search function.

In practice, you can normally try OML first, and if that doesn’t work, OT1, and if that doesn’t work, T1.  Nearly all fonts come in OT1 and T1, but `mathdesign` is one of the few packages that supports OML.

Finally, this is all so much simpler if you can use `unicode-math` in LuaTeX or XeTeX.