# Accessing dutchcal and other fonts directly

Tags: fonts, alphabet, calligraphy

I wanted to define one symbol using the `dutchcal` font, but using the `dutchcal` package ruins the command `\mathcal`.

One workaround was to define another command `\matholdcal` by

```
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\matholdcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
```

and replace `\mathcal` by `\matholdcal` all over the document. It works well although I don't understand the syntax of `\DeclareMathAlphabet`.

But it is a pain to use `\matholdcal` all the time, and creates a mess if I want to copy-paste parts of other documents.

I would like to do the opposite,  leave the command `\mathcal` as it is, and create a new command just for the dutchcal font.

However I don't know how to look for fonts in my LaTeX tree, nor what to put in place of the `OMS` and `cmsy` above.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you checked here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165621/how-to-insert-a-special-math-alphabet

Comment: @MajidAbdolshah I have seen that one but it doesn't give what I am looking for. I would like to use the `dutchcal` font without having to mess up with the `\mathcal` command

Answer (score 7):

I finally found a solution!

Looking into `dutchcal.sty` I found which lines to use instead of calling the package:

```
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathdutchcal}{U}{dutchcal}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathdutchcal}{bold}{U}{dutchcal}{b}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathdutchbcal}{U}{dutchcal}{b}{n}
```

Hope others find it useful.

Comment: I'm running into the exact same problem, I want to use \mathbcal{b} (lowercase) without messing up the normal \mathcal for uppercase. But I don't know enough about latex to understand what I need to do with your 3 lines... I copied them to my preamble without \usepackage{dutchcal} but it doesn't work... If I import dutchcal I'm back to square one...

Comment: I didn’t need lowercase. If you can find a solution please share :-)

Comment: I'm happy to report that your solution works like a charm for lowercase as well. I finally had the time to read the documentation of \DeclareMathAlphabet and I understood that I need to call the duchcal font using \mathdutchcal. Thanks!