# How to use a calligraphy package only for part of the document

Tags: math-mode, packages, package-options, calligraphy

I need to write up a calculation that requires a lowercase calligraphic b, which I got from the following package:

```latex
\usepackage[cal=dutchcal]{mathalfa}
```

However, now other calligraphic letters which I was using, like $\mathcal{L}$ are in the dutchcal font, which is not what I want. Is there any way to only apply the package to specific sections of the document/equations?

Comment: See this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/414430/187728.

It describes how you can create a new macro called `\mathdutchcal` instead of loading the dutchcal directly which overrides `\mathcal`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/414430/187728) describes how to load the `dutchcal` fonts without loading the `dutchcal` package which overrides the default `\mathcal` macro.

Then, you can save the default `\mathcal` macro and override it (using `\let`) only for the desired part of the document. Here is a working example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

% Save the default \mathcal
\let\mathcaldefault\mathcal

% Load the dutchcal font
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathdutchcal}{U}{dutchcal}{m}{n}

\begin{document}

% \mathcal and \mathdutchcal should NOT appear the same
$A, \mathdutchcal{A}, \mathcal{A}$

% Override \mathcal for this part
\let\mathcal\mathdutchcal

% \mathcal and \mathdutchcal should appear the same
$A, \mathdutchcal{A}, \mathcal{A}$

% Reset \mathcal to \mathcaldefault
\let\mathcal\mathcaldefault

% \mathcal and \mathdutchcal should NOT appear the same
$A, \mathdutchcal{A}, \mathcal{A}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: \DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathdutchcal}{U}{dutchcal}{m}{n} does exactly what I needed. Could you explain what the different braces mean?

Comment: You can read about the `\DeclareMathAlphabet` macro [here](https://www.slac.stanford.edu/comp/unix/package/tex/latex/fntguide/node16.html). The arguments are: `\DeclareMathAlphabet {<math-alph>} {<encoding>} {<family>} {<series>} {<shape>}`. So in your case, the encoding is `U` (unknown), series is `m` (medium) and shape is `n` (normal). Note that your font family has to support the series and shape you provide.