# What the type of this special alphabet?

Tags: alphabet

How to add special alphabet like this picture below?

I have read from [How to insert a special math alphabet](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165621/how-to-insert-a-special-math-alphabet), but I confused to determine what the font type of this alphabet.

What the font type of this alphabet?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: The symbol of your picture is done using the `amssymb` package (in math-mode) with the command `\mathfrak{p}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
$\mathfrak{p}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's what I want. Thank you very much @Sebastiano!

Comment: @OngkyDennyWijaya You're welcome and welcome. The next time use this tools to search a symbol: http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html :-) My best regards.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Sebastiano.