# What are "family" and "series" in \DeclareMathAlphabet command?

Tags: fonts

Regarding the command `\DeclareMathAlphabet`, looking at this @cfr's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165621/how-to-insert-a-special-math-alphabet) (the usage), and [this webpage](https://mirror.gutenberg-asso.fr/tex.loria.fr/ctan-doc/macros/latex/doc/html/fntguide/node16.html#:%7E:text=Defines%20to,version%20by%20a%20%5CSetMathAlphabet%20command.) (the documentation), I have the following questions:

1- What are valid values for "family" and "series" arguments, and how I should know what combination represents what symbol?

2- Assuming that `\fontspec` and `unicode-math` are already added, let's say I have included a particular math font whose name is `<name>`. How can I import that name to this command (to fetch one of its symbols)? Should I first call `\DeclareFontFamily` to which `<name>` is fed?

Any pointer to a more verbose documentation of the this command is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fonts in LaTeX are characterized by four attributes (see [`fntguide.pdf`](https://texdoc.org/serve/fntguide/0) for more information):

1. encoding
2. family
3. series
4. shape

If we look in `fontmath.ltx`, we see

```
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbf}{OT1}{cmr}{bx}{n}
```

where the arguments after the command name are in the same order as outlined above. This is the math analog of asking

```
\usefont{OT1}{cmr}{bx}{n}
```

in text, where all four attributes are specified. It's different from `\bfseries` in that the latter only selects the `\bfdefault` attributes (usually `b` or `bx`).

What family names are legal? You can define yourself a family in your document with

```
\DeclareFontFamily{<encoding>}{<name>}{<default commands>}
```

and supplement it with the appropriate `\DeclareFontShape` declarations to associate physical fonts to this family. If a font family name, say `foo`, is unknown to LaTeX, a search in the LaTeX trees is performed for files named `<enc>foo.fd`, where `<enc>` means the encoding current at the time of the font selection request (in uppercased or lowercased versions). If no such file is found, the family name will be substituted with the default `cmr`.

Now you know what family names are legal: just browse your TeX distribution for files with extension `.fd`. And looking in them you can see what series and shape combinations are available.

**Caveat.** Several `.fd` files depend on bits of information gathered elsewhere, because they are accompanying specific packages (an outstanding example are the `.fd` files that accompany `newtxtext` and `newtxmath`), so using them may not be possible “directly”, but the relevant information can usually be extracted without too much labor.