# MiKTeX automatically updated and now is taking fonts from a different place

Tags: fonts, miktex

Regarding [my recent edit to my question about different versions of `\mathcal{F}`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11265/are-there-two-different-versions-of-the-mathcalf-character), I've noticed that after I recently automatically updated my MiKTeX, it's taking fonts from a different place whenever possible. Where I used to get a bunch of messages at the end of my .log file that looked like

`<C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx10.pfb>`

the messages now look like

`<C:/WINDOWS/Fonts/cmbx10.pfb>`

Is there anything to do about this? The only character I've so far noticed looking different is `\mathcal{F}` (I'm getting the "old" one instead of the "new" one; other `\mathcal` characters look the same, and I'm still getting the current `\delta` and the math arrows with the bigger arrowheads).

Currently I'm using pdfLaTeX, pdfTeX Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (MiKTeX 2.9.6400), and TeXworks Version 0.6.2.

EDIT (1/29/2018): I recently automatically updated my MiKTeX again---currently I'm using pdfLaTeX, pdfTeX Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (MiKTeX 2.9.6600), and TeXworks Version 0.6.2---and it seems to be taking fonts from the old place once again (i.e., not the place on C:/WINDOWS). And thus my `\mathcal{F}` and all other characters look to be in the current form. I don't know what I did.

Comment: The windows Fonts folder is part of search path for fonts. This isn't new. But I don't know the search order compared to the texmf-trees -- I never had the same type1 fonts in both locations.  Why do you have the fonts there? Can't you simply delete them? there seem to be old anyway.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, I don't own this computer, and I suspect there are other programs on it that need the fonts in the Windows directory to be able to use them.

Comment: By any chance, were you compiling with a different compiler? Say, pdflatex in one case, XeTeX in another case?

Comment: @RobtAll, no, I'd always been using pdfLaTeX.